# Calculating hitting probabilities of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain with state space $$S = \{1, 2, \dots, 4, 5\}$$ and transition matrix
$$P =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac 1 2 & \frac 1 2 & 0\\
\frac 1 2 & 0 & \frac 1 2 & 0 & 0\\
\frac 1 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 2 & 0\\
0 & \frac 1 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Suppose $X_0 = 3$. What is the probability that the chain hits state $5$ before it hits state $1$?

**My working**

Let $U_i$ be the probability that the chain, starting in state $i$, hits state $5$ before it hits state $1$ and we have the following system of linear equations:
$$U_2 = \frac 1 2 U_3,$$
$$U_3 = \frac 1 2 U_4$$
and
$$U_4 = \frac 1 2 U_2 + \frac 1 2.$$
Solving this, we have $$U_3 = \frac 2 7,$$ which is also, by definition, the probability that the chain starts in state $3$ and hits state $5$ before hitting state $1$.

---

As I am just beginning to learn about Markov chains, this is my first time encountering such a problem and I would like to know if my working and answer are correct. Otherwise, do kindly point out where I have gone wrong and why :)

Comment: This looks correct to me :)

Comment: @nejimban Thank you! I also have another question on the same problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253771/calculating-hitting-times-of-a-markov-chain) and was wondering if you could check it for me :)