# Calculating hitting times of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain with state space $$S = \{1, 2, \dots, 4, 5\}$$ and transition matrix
$$P =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac 1 2 & \frac 1 2 & 0\\
\frac 1 2 & 0 & \frac 1 2 & 0 & 0\\
\frac 1 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 2 & 0\\
0 & \frac 1 2 & 0 & 0 & \frac 1 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Let $$k_i = \mathbb{E}_i(T_5),$$ where $$T_y = \min\{n \geq 1 : X_n = y\}\ \forall\ y \in S.$$ By using a first step analysis, determine the corresponding equations for the $k_i$ as well as the numerical value of $k_1$.

**My working**

$$\begin{aligned}
k_1 & = \sum^5_{x = 0} \mathbb{E}_1(T_5 \mid X_1 = x)\mathbb{P}_1(X_1 = x)\\[1 mm]
& = (1 + k_3)\frac 1 2 + (1 + k_4)\frac 1 2\\[1 mm]
& = 1 + \frac 1 2 k_3 + \frac 1 2 k_4
\end{aligned}$$
Similarly, we have
$$k_2 = 1 + \frac 1 2 k_1 + \frac 1 2 k_3,$$
$$k_3 = 1 + \frac 1 2 k_1 + \frac 1 2 k_4$$
and
$$k_4 = 1 + \frac 1 2 k_2.$$
Solving this, we have $$k_1 = 7.$$

---

As I am just beginning to learn about Markov chains, this is my first time encountering such a problem and I would like to know if my working and answer are correct. Otherwise, do kindly point out where I have gone wrong and why :)

Comment: Also correct, well done :)

Comment: What does the notation $\mathbb{E}_i(X)$ mean? Like what does the subscript of $i$ mean.

Comment: @AlanAbraham oh it means starting in state $i$. Sorry, I forgot to include that!

Comment: Related question by same author: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253754/calculating-hitting-probabilities-of-a-markov-chain

Comment: @PeterO. Yes, that was by me too. Although the background is the same, but the concepts are different so I thought it best to separate them!